# Ajuda com script de requisição assíncrona

Tags: php, javascript, html, pdo

Este formulário terá o objetivo de agendamento para consulta, com o cliente selecionando o profissional desejado, e tendo um calendário com os dias semanais selecionáveis para atendimento.

Por exemplo:

O Drº Rogério atende de 2ª a Sábado.

Já a Drª Ludmila atende somente as 3ª e 5ª

Até ai esta tudo funcionando as mil maravilhas.

O meu problema esta na troca (em uma nova Seleção) dos profissionais.

Quando seleciono a Drª Ludmila e visualizo o seu calendário de atendimento, mas quando tento altera-lo para o calendário do Drª Rogério fazendo uma nova seleção de profissional, ele continua me trazendo o calendário da Drª Ludmila.

Só consigo efetuar a troca do calendário dando uma atualização na página, e refazendo todo o procedimento e selecionando o Drº Rogério, para carregar o seu calendário

Posto esse [endereço](https://www.pbfjacarepagua.com.br/calendario/) provisório para visualizarem o problema, com um link para os Download dos aquivos usados.

Se os amigos puderem me dar uma luz, de como posso fazer para alterar os calendários me diante a seleção do profissional sem ter que recarregar a página, ficarei muito agradecido.

Desde já meus agradecimentos pela sua atenção.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro de seu arquivo calendario.php
Adicione a seguinte linha `$("#datepicker").datepicker("destroy");`

seu codigo ficará assim

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#datepicker").datepicker("destroy");
            $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                beforeShowDay:function(date)
            {
            var day = date.getDay();
            var month = date.getMonth();
            var currDate = date.getDate();
            '.$datepicker['formato_calendario'].'
            {return [false];}
            else
            return [true];

        }});
    });
</script>
```

O que está acontecendo é que você já possui uma  instancia do datapicker e está
tentando adicionar outra, mas  para isso você precisa destruir a atual

Comment: Valeu Marcos Brinner , só tive que alterar  de class(.) para id(#), e funcionou perfeito. Obrigado pela sua atenção ao meu problema.
Veja o resultado no endereço provisório -
 (https://www.pbfjacarepagua.com.br/calendario/), Abraços.

Comment: agora sim, que bom  q  deu, vou  editar minh resposta :) se puder marca-la como  correta basta clicar no  ✓

Comment: Valeu Marcos Brinner, já marquei como Útil a sua resposta. E como você já deve ter verificado no endereço provisório, estou removendo-o. Mais uma vez obrigado pela a ajuda,