# Continuação de Ajuda com script de requisição assíncrona

Tags: php, javascript, html, pdo

Resolvi com a ajuda do Marcos Brinner, o problema que estava com o DetePicker conforme o [post anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/262048/ajuda-com-script-de-requisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ass%C3%ADncrona).

Porém pintou uma outra duvida em relação a requisição assíncrona, entre o DetePicker (Calendário) e os Horários.

Achei que seguindo o raciocínio das outras requisições anteriores, pudesse trazer os horários de atendimento individual de cada profissional, ao selecionar a data desejada e disponível em seu calendário. Mas sem sucesso.

Contando com a ajuda dos amigos para entender o porque, estou postando um [endereço provisório](https://www.pbfjacarepagua.com.br/calendario/) para que os amigos possam ver o que está acontecendo (Ou melhor dizendo, o que não está acontecendo).

No endereço os amigos poderão fazer o Download dos arquivos usados e também das imagens das tabelas Calendário e Horários.

Desde já meus agradecimentos à todos, pela atenção ao meu problema.

Comment: Você testou se a data está pegando corretamente do datePicker? Tente assim `var cod_Calendario = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate'); `

Comment: Olá Dobrychtop, fiz o que sugeriu e agora ele esta me trazendo somente os ID 1 e 12, ambos com valores "0" na coluna "cod_calendario". Pode dar uma olhada lá no endereço provisório, pois deixei a com a sua sugestão, valeu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos lá, primeiramente, assim que o usuário seleciona um caledario, além de retornar o formato do mesmo, você pode colocar o `ID` do calendário em um campo oculto, para usar ele mais tarde para a busca dos horários.

Para pegar a data do datepicker do jQuery UI você precisa fazer assim

```
var data = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
data =  $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', data);
```

Mais informações: https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate

Dessa forma você vai pegar a data, e formatar ela para o ISO_8601(yy-mm-dd), que é padrão da gravação no banco de dados.

Seu banco de dados não está seguindo as regras formais, coloquei no *DRIVE* um `DER` e uma imagem de como ele deveria estar, ele não está 100% nas regras, por exemplo, a data grava direto na tabela `agendar`, ela poderia ser gravada e uma tabela externa e passado só o `ID` dela para a `agendar`.

Mais sobre regras formais:
https://imasters.com.br/artigo/7020/banco-de-dados/modelagem-de-dados-final-normalizacao/?trace=1519021197&source=single

Quando você gravar uma consulta, você altera o `status` do horário para indisponível, e compara ele nas consultas, para trazer apenas os horários disponíveis, pode deixar 0 para disponível e 1 para não disponível, você escolhe.

Nesse caso sua consulta fica assim, porém vai precisar mudar ela se normalizar o BD

```
"SELECT * FROM calendarios as c inner join horarios as h where c.cod_calendario = " . $_POST['cod_prof']. " and h.status = 0";
```

Espero que isso ajude!

Comment: Inseri a linha que você sugeriu Dobrychtop, mas sem sucesso. Atualizei os arquivos com a alteração feita, se quiser analisar, OK. Eu reparei que tanto em Especialidades como em Profissionais, estou usando Option com Value validos, poderia ser pelo DatePicker ser um Input e consequentemente sem nenhum Value valido???

Comment: O usuário vai selecionar uma data, correto? Você está comparando essa data selecionada pelo usuário com alguma data no seu banco? Na sua nomenclatura, o que o cod_calendario é, uma data mesmo? Se sim, você pode colocar um `alert(cod_calendario);` pra testar se a data pega corretamente.

Comment: O que eu gostaria, mas não tenho idéia de como fazer ou mesmo pesquisar, seria criar um agendamento de consulta da seguinte formar:

O cliente seleciona a especialidade, o profissional, apos isso o sistema me mostra um calendário com os dias de atendimento disponíveis para o profissional selecionado.

Se todos os horários referentes ao dia forem agendados, o dia se tornaria indisponível para seleção no calendário.

Comment: Caso já tenha ocorrido algum agendamento para um determinado dia, esse horário agendado não aparecerá mais para seleção, ficando apenas os horários disponíveis para esse dia.

Tem idéia de onde posso pesquisar sobre isso?.

Comment: Vc está no caminho, eu poderia ajudar mais sabendo a estrutura do seu banco de dados, mas vendo o que vc já tem, só falta a última parte, seu calendário já está deixando selecionar só os dias disponíveis, correto?

Comment: Agora vc já tem o dia que o usuário selecionou, basta fazer uma consulta na sua tabela de horários, comparando a data que o usuário escolheu, e então trazer os horários disponíveis naquele dia selecionado, você poderia ter uma coluna do "status" do horário, pra saber se ele está selecionado ou não.

Comment: Você pode criar uma tabela para cruzar os dados, nela vai o ID do profissional e o ID do horário, pra você saber qual profissional tem agendado qual horário.

Comment: Estou postando para download pelo endereço provisório a estrutura do BD, valeu?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70132/discussion-between-murilo-and-dobrychtop).